# What are all the dual progression prestige classes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, multi-classing, prestige-class, class

A dual progression prestige class is one that progresses two class features, usually spellcasting, manifesting, invocations, etc. at once. These prestige classes are typically intended for multiclass characters who want to progress the features of two classes (though there occasionally exist ways to enter the class without being multiclassed).

Prestige classes such as the Arcane Trickster would fall under what I am looking for, because they are progressing Sneak Attack and Spellcasting, it is a class for multiclass characters intending to progress the features of two separate classes together.

The progression of Spellcasting is typically denoted in the "Spells Per Day" section of a prestige class' features, as well as in the progression chart.

The obvious and perhaps most iconic Dual Progression prestige class is the Mystic Theurge from the Dungeon Master's Guide:

> When a new mystic theurge level is gained, the character gains new
> spells per day as if he had also gained a level in any one arcane
> spellcasting class he belonged to before he added the prestige class
> and any one divine spellcasting class he belonged to previously.

Mystic Theurge, obviously, is a dual progression prestige class for Arcane/Divine.

Here are the other prestige classes I am aware of that have a dual progression mechanic:

- Mystic Theurge (Arcane/Divine)
- Ultimate Magus (Spontaneous Arcane/Prepared Arcane)
- Fochlucan Lyrist (Arcane/Divine)
- Cerebremancer (Arcane/Psionic)
- Eldritch Theurge (Arcane/Invocation)
- Eldritch Disciple (Divine/Invocation)
- Arcane Hierophant (Arcane/Divine)
- Arcane Trickster (Sneak Attack/Arcane)
- Sacred Fist (Unarmed Strike/Divine)
- Rage Mage (Rage/Arcane)
- Jade Phoenix Mage (Arcane/Manuevers)
- Ruby Knight Vindicator (Divine/Maneuvers
- Anima Mage (Arcane/Vestige)

Are there any dual progression prestige classes that I am missing?

---

*A small note, technically classes that progress full or 3/4ths Base Attack Bonus and Spellcasting ability are considered dual progression classes, such as the Abjurant Champion or the Eldritch Knight. The logic being that they are progressing both martial ability and spellcasting ability. However, there is an extreme amount of "Gish" prestige classes, so I suspect there would be too many to list.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I plan to answer this more thoroughly (and more appropriately Stack formatted), but for now, [here is a spreadsheet I made years ago with a dual-progression matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TOSK4m7pMAyC__nr8WnotV0AsJYdYiEiKO0vcBjCoiE/edit?usp=sharing). Columns and rows are base classes, intersections list which prestige classes can advance both. It’s fairly thorough though I know it’s not 100% comprehensive.

And, so this isn’t link-only, not that this is terribly useful in this state, the matrix:

|  | Arc | Ard | Art | Brb | Brd | Beg | Bnd | Clr | Cru | DiM | DSh | DfA | DrN | Dru | Dsk | FSo | Fit | Hex | Inc | Knt | Lrk | Mar | Mnk | Nin | Pal | Psi | PsW | Rng | Rog | Sam | Sct | Shc | Shu | Sor | Slb | SKn | SpT | SSh | Swa | SwS | Tot | Tru | Wrb | Wrl | Wrm | Wld | Wiz | WuJ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Arc** | X | PT |  |  | MT | MT |  |  |  | PT | ME |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  | PT | ME | SF |  |  | PT | PT | ME | ShS/ME |  |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  |  |  |  |  | ED | MT | PT | MT | MT |
| **Ard** | PT | X |  |  | CM | CM |  | PT |  |  |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  |  |  |  |  | PT |  |  | PT | PA |  |  | PT | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM |  | CM | CM |
| **Art** |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Brb** |  |  |  | X | RM | RM |  |  |  |  |  |  | RM |  | RM |  |  | RM |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | RM |  |  | RM |  |  |  | TR |  |  |  | RM |  | RM | RM |
| **Brd** | MT | CM |  | RM | X |  | AM | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | FL/AH/MT |  | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM | ME | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **Beg** | MT | CM |  | RM |  | X | AM | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT |  | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM | ME | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **Bnd** |  |  |  |  | AM | AM | X | TA |  |  |  |  | AM |  | AM |  |  | AM |  |  |  |  |  |  | TA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | AM | AM |
| **Clr** |  | PT |  |  | MT | MT | TA | X | RKV | PT | ME |  | MT/TN |  | MT |  |  | MT | SH |  |  | ME | SF |  |  | PT | PT | ME | ShS/ME |  |  | MT |  | MT/TN | SH |  | MT |  |  | RKV | SH |  | RKV | ED | MT | PT | MT/TN | MT |
| **Cru** |  |  |  |  | JPM | JPM |  | RKV | X |  |  |  | JPM |  | JPM |  |  | JPM |  |  |  |  | SSN |  | RKV |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | JPM |  |  | JPM |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | JPM |  | JPM | JPM |
| **DiM** | PT |  |  |  | CM | CM |  | PT |  | X |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  |  |  |  |  | PT |  |  | PT | PA |  |  | PT | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM |  | CM | CM |
| **DSh** | ME |  |  |  | ME | ME |  | ME |  |  | X |  | ME | ME | ME | ME |  | ME |  |  |  |  |  |  | ME |  |  | ME | ME |  |  |  | ME | ME |  |  | ME | ME |  |  |  |  |  |  | ME |  | ME | ME |
| **DfA** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | EF |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **DrN** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  | AM | MT/TN | JPM | CM | ME |  | X | AH/MT |  | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM | ME | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **Dru** |  | PT |  |  | FL/AH/MT | AH/MT |  |  |  | PT | ME |  | AH/MT | X | AH/MT |  |  | AH/MT |  |  | PT | ME | SF |  | HO | PT | PT | ME | DS/ME |  |  | MT |  | AH/MT |  |  | AH/MT |  |  |  |  |  |  | ED | AH/MT | PT | AH/MT | AH/MT |
| **Dsk** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  | AM | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT | X | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM | ME | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **FSo** |  | PT |  |  | MT | MT |  |  |  | PT | ME |  | MT |  | MT | X |  | MT |  |  | PT | ME | SF |  |  | PT | PT | ME | ShS/ME |  |  | MT |  | MT |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ED | MT | PT | MT | MT |
| **Fit** |  |  |  |  | EK | EK |  |  |  |  |  |  | EK |  | EK |  | X | EK |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | EK |  |  | EK |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | EK |  | EK | EK |
| **Hex** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  | AM | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT |  | MT | EK | X | SC |  | CM | ME | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  |  | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **Inc** |  | SM |  |  | SC | SC |  | SH |  | SM |  |  | SC |  | SC |  |  | SC | X |  | SM |  |  |  |  | SM | SM |  |  |  |  |  |  | SC |  |  | SC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | SC | SM | SC | SC |
| **Knt** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Lrk** | PT |  |  |  | CM | CM |  |  |  |  |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  | X |  |  |  | PT |  |  | PT | PA |  |  |  | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM |  | CM | CM |
| **Mar** | ME |  |  |  | ME | ME |  | ME |  |  |  |  | ME | ME | ME | ME |  | ME |  |  |  | X |  |  | ME |  |  | ME |  |  |  |  | ME | ME |  |  | ME | ME |  |  |  |  |  |  | ME |  | ME | ME |
| **Mnk** | SF |  |  |  | EF | EF |  | SF | SSN |  |  | EF | EF | SF | EF | SF |  | EF |  |  |  |  | X |  | SF |  |  | SF |  |  |  |  | SF | EF |  | Ata | EF | SF |  | SSN |  |  | SSN | EF | EF |  | EF | EF |
| **Nin** |  |  |  |  | US | US |  |  |  |  |  |  | US |  | US |  |  | US |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | US |  |  | US |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | US |  | US | US |
| **Pal** |  | PT |  |  | MT | MT | TA |  | RKV | PT | ME |  | MT | HO | MT |  |  | MT |  |  | PT |  | SF |  | X | PT | PT | HO/ME | ShS/ME |  |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  | RKV |  |  | RKV | ED | MT | PT | MT | MT |
| **Psi** | PT |  |  |  | CM | CM |  | PT |  |  |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  |  |  |  |  | PT | X |  | PT | PA |  |  |  | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM |  | CM | CM |
| **PsW** | PT |  |  |  | CM | CM |  | PT |  |  |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  |  |  |  |  | PT |  | X | PT | PA |  |  |  | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM |  | CM | CM |
| **Rng** | ME | PT |  |  | MT/ME | MT/ME |  | ME |  | PT | ME |  | MT/ME | ME | MT/ME | ME |  | MT/ME |  |  | PT |  | SF |  | HO/ME | PT | PT | X | DS*/ME |  |  | MT |  | MT/ME |  |  | MT/ME |  |  |  |  |  |  | ED | MT/ME |  | MT/ME | MT/ME |
| **Rog** | ShS/ME | PA |  |  | US/DM/AT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | ShS/ME |  | PA | ME |  | US/DM/AT/ME | DS/ME | US/DM/AT/ME | ShS/ME |  | US/DM/AT/ME |  |  | PA |  |  |  | ShS/ME | PA | PA | DS*/ME | X |  |  |  |  | US/DM/AT/ME |  |  | US/DM/AT/ME |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | US/DM/AT/ME | PA | US/DM/AT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |
| **Sam** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Sct** |  |  |  |  | US | US |  |  |  |  |  |  | US |  | US |  |  | US |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  | US |  |  | US |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | US | US |
| **Shc** | MT | PT |  |  | NM/MT | NM/MT |  | MT |  | PT |  |  | NM/MT | MT | NM/MT | MT |  | NM/MT |  |  |  |  |  |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  |  | X | MT | NM/MT |  |  | NM/MT | MT |  |  |  |  |  |  | NM/MT | PT | NM/MT | NM/MT |
| **Shu** |  | PT |  |  | MT | MT |  |  |  | PT | ME |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  | PT |  | SF |  |  | PT | PT |  |  |  |  | MT | X | MT |  |  | MT |  |  |  |  |  |  | ED | MT | PT | MT | MT |
| **Sor** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  | AM | MT/TN | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT |  | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM |  | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT | X | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **Slb** |  | SM |  |  | SC | SC |  | SH |  | SM |  |  | SC |  | SC |  |  | SC |  |  | SM |  |  |  |  | SM | SM |  |  |  |  |  |  | SC | X |  | SC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | SC | SM | SC | SC |
| **SKn** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Ata |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **SpT** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  |  | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT |  |  | EK |  | SC |  | CM |  | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  | X | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET |  | CM | UM | UM |
| **SSh** |  | PT |  |  | MT | MT |  |  |  | PT | ME |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT |  |  | PT |  | SF |  |  | PT | PT |  |  |  |  | MT |  | MT |  |  | MT | X |  |  |  |  |  | ED | MT | PT | MT | MT |
| **Swa** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **SwS** |  |  |  |  | JPM | JPM |  | RKV |  |  |  |  | JPM |  | JPM |  |  | JPM |  |  |  |  | SSN |  | RKV |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | JPM |  |  | JPM |  |  | X |  |  |  |  | JPM |  | JPM | JPM |
| **Tot** |  | SM |  | TR | SC | SC |  | SH |  | SM |  |  | SC |  | SC |  |  | SC |  |  | SM |  |  |  |  | SM | SM |  |  |  |  |  |  | SC |  |  | SC |  |  |  | X |  |  |  | SC | SM | SC | SC |
| **Tru** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Wrb** |  |  |  |  | JPM | JPM |  | RKV |  |  |  |  | JPM |  | JPM |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | SSN |  | RKV |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | JPM |  |  | JPM |  |  |  |  |  | X |  | JPM |  | JPM | JPM |
| **Wrl** | ED |  |  |  | ET | ET |  | ED |  |  |  |  | ET | ED | ET | ED |  | ET |  |  |  |  | EF |  | ED |  |  | ED |  |  |  |  | ED | ET |  |  | ET | ED |  |  |  |  |  | X | ET |  | ET | ET |
| **Wrm** | MT | CM |  | RM |  |  |  | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  |  | AH/MT |  | MT | EK |  | SC |  | CM |  | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  |  | NM/MT | MT |  | SC |  |  | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET | X | CM | UM | UM |
| **Wld** | PT |  |  |  | CM | CM |  | PT |  |  |  |  | CM | PT | CM | PT |  | CM | SM |  |  |  |  |  | PT |  |  |  | PA |  |  | PT | PT | CM | SM |  | CM | PT |  |  | SM |  |  |  | CM | X | CM | CM |
| **Wiz** | MT | CM |  | RM | UM | UM | AM | MT/TN | JPM | CM | ME |  | UM | AH/MT | UM | MT | EK | UM | SC |  | CM |  | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT | UM | SC |  | UM | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET | UM | CM | X |  |
| **WuJ** | MT | CM |  | RM | UM | UM | AM | MT | JPM | CM | ME |  | UM | AH/MT | UM | MT | EK | UM | SC |  | CM |  | EF | US | MT | CM | CM | MT/ME | US/DM/AT/ME |  | US | NM/MT | MT | UM | SC |  | UM | MT |  | JPM | SC |  | JPM | ET | UM | CM |  | X |

X is used to mark a class’s intersection with itself. Terrible choice on my part but oh well.

Beyond that, the abbreviations:

Base classes:

- Arc: archivist (divine, prepared using a book)
- Ard: ardent (psionic)
- Brb: barbarian (rage)
- Beg: beguiler (arcane, full-list spontaneous)
- Bnd: binder (vestiges)
- Clr: cleric (divine, prepared)
- Cru: crusader (initiating)
- DiM: divine mind (psionic)
- DSh: dragon shaman (draconic auras)
- DfA: dragonfire adept (invocations)
- DrN: dread necromancer (arcane, full-list spontaneous)
- Dru: druid (divine, prepared)
- Dsk: duskblade (arcane, spontaneous)
- FSo: favored soul (divine, spontaneous)
- Fit: fighter (fighter bonus feats, fighter level for reqs)
- Hex: hexblade (arcane, spontaneous)
- Inc: incarnate (soulmelds)
- Knt: knight (knight’s challenges, I guess, not that anything advances it)
- Lrk: lurk (psionic)
- Mar: marshal (auras)
- Mnk: monk (unarmed strike, unarmored AC, flurry of blows)
- Nin: ninja (sudden strike)
- Pal: paladin (divine, prepared; smite)
- Psi: psion (psionic)
- PsW: psychic warrior (psionic)
- Rng: ranger (divine, prepared)
- Rog: rogue (sneak attack)
- Sam: samurai (nothing?)
- Sct: scout (skirmish)
- Shc: shadowcaster (mysteries)
- Shu: shugenja (divine, prepared)
- Sor: sorcerer (arcane, spontaneous)
- Slb: soulborn (soulmelds)
- SKn: soulknife (mind blade)
- SSh: spirit shaman (divine, spontaneous but can change spells known each day)
- Swa: swashbuckler (grace?)
- SwS: swordsage (sublime maneuvers)
- Tot: totemist (soulmelds)
- Tru: truenamer (truenaming)
- Wrb: warblade (sublime maneuvers)
- Wrl: warlock (invocations)
- Wrm: warmage (arcane, full-list spontaneous)
- Wld: wilder (psionic)
- Wiz: wizard (arcane, prepared from a book)
- WuJ: wu jen (arcane, prepared from a book)

Prestige classes:

- AM: anima mage
- AH: arcane hierophant
- AT: arcane trickster
- Ata: atavist
- CM: cerebremancer
- DM: daggerspell mage
- DS: daggerspell shaper
- ED: eldritch disciple
- EF: enlightened fist
- EK: eldritch knight
- ET: eldritch theurge
- FL: Fochlucan lyrist
- JPM: jade phoenix mage
- ME: mythic exemplar
- MT: mystic theurge
- NM: noctumancer
- PT: psychic theurge
- RKV: ruby knight vindicator
- SF: sacred fist
- ShS: shadowbane stalker
- SSN: shadow sun ninja
- SC: soul caster
- SM: soul manifester
- RM: rage mage
- TA: Tenebrous apostate
- TN: true necromancer
- UM: ultimate magus
- US: unseen seer

Comment: “Tell me your edition is overcrowded with classes without telling me your edition is overcrowded with classes”.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I mean, “over” is subjective. This is literally what I love about 3.5e; almost nothing else about the edition is good, but the vast quantity of material and its ability to be mixed and matched is very compelling to the right mindset.

Comment: Fair enough. I think the left most column would benefit from being bolded, I’d do it myself if I were at my desktop, but doing it on my phone is a torment I wouldn’t wish upon my enemies.

Comment: I'm guessing that DS is Daggerspell Shaper, ShS is Shadowbane Stalker, both from Complete Adventurer. ME might be Mythic Exemplar

Comment: @Chemus Yes, those are indeed likely the culprits.

Answer (score -1):

A few that come to my mind:

1. Necromancy classes: Yathrinshee and True Necromancer. Both Divine + Arcane.
2. Unseen Seer (Arcane + Sneak Attack).
3. [Prestigious Character Classes](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/prestigiousCharacterClasses.htm) lets you have, say, Wizard progression and Bard progression in the same class, so you might count these.
4. Mind Mage (Arcane + Psionic)
5. Psychic Theurge (Divine + Psionic)
6. Tenebrous Apostate (Divine + Binding)
7. Soulcaster (Incarnum + Arcane)
8. Soul Manifester (Incarnum + Psionic)
9. Sapphire Hierarch (Incarnum + Divine)
10. Noctumancer (Honestly, I don't understand these guys)

Comment: Any explanation on the downvotes here? Whatever is causing them, I'm completely blind to it.

Comment: for my part, it’s a partial answer. Meaning that it can’t stand on its own and is a poor answer to the question.

Comment: to me, it's not a partial answer, it's helpful; it lacks sources but that's what internet is for. Also, I want to add the Green Whisperer (bard / druid spellcasting) from Dragon #311 https://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/prestige/general/greenwhisperer.shtml and the Mind Mage (psionic / arcane) from Dragon #313 https://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/prestige/psionic/mindmage.shtml